# SAML 2.0 without a browser

Tags: authentication, identity, saml, delegation, federation

Let's say I have a system that's currently like this:

1. Monolithic Web App: Contains its own accounts and relies upon clients to log-in with (essentially) HTTP BasicAuth.  That is, the username & password are getting passed to the server.
2. Thick Client: Logs-in to the above app, receives access token it uses thereafter for REST API calls.

Basically, I'd like to transform the above into this sort of system:

1. SAML 2.0 IdP:  System of record for identities
2. Same Web App, minus Authentication responsibility
3. Thick Client: Unchanged. <-- *hard requirement*

So, crucially, I can't have the thick client do the standard SAML 2.0 Browser SSO redirects.  Is there any solution?   Essentially, I'd like the same functionality as OAuth2's `password_grant`, but in the SAML 2.0 world.

Doing some research, I've come across the SAML [Enhanced Client or Proxy](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/ECP#ECP-WhatAboutNon-Web/HTTPProtocols), but support seems spotty.  The frustrating thing is, I *have the darn credential in cleartext* at the WebApp; is there some simple way to make this work?

Would the [HTTP Artifact Binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#HTTP_Artifact_Binding) do the trick?

Comment: At this point, I'm just going to have the web-app use Watir or Mechanize to fill-in the forms, click submit and screen-scrape the response.  Sure it's a hack, but not seeing any options, and nothing but crickets here.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: This question should perhaps better be asked on https://security.stackexchange.com/.**

If you cannot change the thick client, then you cannot use SAML, or any form of browser-based single sign-on (SSO). It's as simple as that.

Also, your approach of expecting users to type their SSO credentials into the thick client, and then sending them through HTTP basic auth and automatically typing them into a form is insecure for several reasons:

1. The user's plain text password needs to be passed through several instances that should never see it, and it will probably also be stored in the thick client. Even if it is encrypted (in transit or at rest), this is less secure than the password being only stored as a hash on the IdP (and in the memory or password manager of the user).
2. Expecting users to enter their SSO credentials anywhere else than the login form of the IdP promotes dangerous use of credentials which can make users more susceptible to phishing.

If you are planning to use the IdP for SSO to more than one client than this one legacy thick client, you can use something like *application passwords*:

1. The user logs in to a web app using SSO (SAML)
2. The user creates an application password (and also has the option to revoke it)
3. The application password is then used with the thick client.

The "application password" can be a combination of a simple unique ID (which is entered as the "username") and a long random-generated string (which is sent as the "password"). If the thick client can store these credentials, then this approach would be somewhat user-friendly, although not as secure as true SSO.

In the long run, do consider updating the thick client.